# Auto sql of azure SQL based on DTU consumption alert

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I have to scale my Azure SQL if DTU utilization is high at any moment and scale down if consumption is low for a certain duration.

I know this can be done by setting alert rule and web hook but looking for some redimate stuff which i can refer and utilize it....

Answer (score 2):

Scale up and down takes time and sometimes it takes more than expected. It usually takes 5-10 minutes but sometimes it takes 25-30 minutes. The busier the database is at the time of the scale, the more time it takes to scale up or down. The size of the database also matters.

Remember also that transactions are rolled back when a scale is in progress.

My suggestion is to use the following query to identify patterns in resource consumption and then automate the scale up and down of the database.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
ORDER BY end_time
```

Tabulate that data on hours and days of the week to facilitate the pattern identification. After that use Azure Automation and parts of the following PowerShell to automate the scale up/down of the database. The following PowerShell does all what you want, it monitors DTU usage and then based on consumption triggers a scale process.

```
# Login-AzureRmAccount
# Set the resource group name and location for your server
$resourcegroupname = "myResourceGroup-$(Get-Random)"
$location = "southcentralus"
# Set an admin login and password for your server
$adminlogin = "ServerAdmin"
$password = "ChangeYourAdminPassword1"
# The logical server name has to be unique in the system
$servername = "server-$(Get-Random)"
# The sample database name
$databasename = "mySampleDatabase"
# The ip address range that you want to allow to access your server
$startip = "0.0.0.0"
$endip = "0.0.0.0"

# Create a new resource group
$resourcegroup = New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourcegroupname -Location $location

# Create a new server with a system wide unique server name
$server = New-AzureRmSqlServer -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname `
    -ServerName $servername `
    -Location $location `
    -SqlAdministratorCredentials $(New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $adminlogin, $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))

# Create a server firewall rule that allows access from the specified IP range
$serverfirewallrule = New-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname `
    -ServerName $servername `
    -FirewallRuleName "AllowedIPs" -StartIpAddress $startip -EndIpAddress $endip

# Create a blank database with S0 performance level
$database = New-AzureRmSqlDatabase  -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname `
    -ServerName $servername `
    -DatabaseName $databasename -RequestedServiceObjectiveName "S0"

# Monitor the DTU consumption on the imported database in 5 minute intervals
$MonitorParameters = @{
  ResourceId = "/subscriptions/$($(Get-AzureRMContext).Subscription.Id)/resourceGroups/$resourcegroupname/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/$servername/databases/$databasename"
  TimeGrain = [TimeSpan]::Parse("00:05:00")
  MetricNames = "dtu_consumption_percent"

}
(Get-AzureRmMetric @MonitorParameters -DetailedOutput).MetricValues

# Scale the database performance to Standard S1
$database = Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname `
    -ServerName $servername `
    -DatabaseName $databasename `
    -Edition "Standard" `
    -RequestedServiceObjectiveName "S1"

# Set an alert rule to automatically monitor DTU in the future
Add-AzureRMMetricAlertRule -ResourceGroup $resourcegroupname `
    -Name "MySampleAlertRule" `
    -Location $location `
    -TargetResourceId "/subscriptions/$($(Get-AzureRMContext).Subscription.Id)/resourceGroups/$resourcegroupname/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/$servername/databases/$databasename" `
    -MetricName "dtu_consumption_percent" `
    -Operator "GreaterThan" `
    -Threshold 90 `
    -WindowSize $([TimeSpan]::Parse("00:05:00")) `
    -TimeAggregationOperator "Average" `
    -Actions $(New-AzureRmAlertRuleEmail -SendToServiceOwners)

# Clean up deployment 
# Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname
```

Comment: Please Up Vote and comment: (Auto Scaling for Azure SQL) - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/16839646-auto-scaling-for-azure-sql

Comment: Thank you for sharing this feedback item with us Mike.